# NLP NER RegexNER Can I include annotators using NERClassifierCombiner

Tags: stanford-nlp

Can I add the call to the properties file:

```
java -cp stanford-corenlp-3.5.2.jar -mx1g edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERClassifierCombiner -loadClassifier c2is2.serialized.ncc.ncc.ser.gz -map word=0,answer=1 -props c2is2nlp.props -textFile c2is2r3.txt
```

Here is the error stack:

```
NERClassifierCombiner invoked on Mon Jul 20 13:08:20 EDT 2015 with arguments:
   -loadClassifier c2is2.serialized.ncc.ncc.ser.gz -map word=0,answer=1 -props c2is2nlp.props -textFile c2is2r3.txt
loadClassifier=c2is2.serialized.ncc.ncc.ser.gz
regexner.mapping=c2is2Mapping.tab
Unknown property: |regexner.mapping|
textFile=c2is2r3.txt
map=word=0,answer=1
annotators=tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref
Unknown property: |annotators|
map=word=0,answer=1
```

Do I need to add the following:

```
edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP [ -props <YOUR CONFIGURATION FILE> ]
```

Here:

```
java -cp stanford-corenlp-3.5.2.jar -mx1g edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERClassifierCombiner -loadClassifier c2is2.serialized.ncc.ncc.ser.gz -map word=0,answer=1 -textFile c2is2r3.txt
```

Here are the working steps:

Token file

```
more c2is2r3.tsv
The O
fate    O
of  O
Lehman  ORGANIZATION    
Brothers    ORGANIZATION
. . .
New ORGANIZATION
York    ORGANIZATION
Fed ORGANIZATION
,   O
and O
Treasury    TITLE
Secretary   TITLE
Henry   PERSON
M.  PERSON
Paulson PERSON
Jr. PERSON
.   O
```

Property file:

```
more c2is2r3.prop

trainFile = c2is2r3.tsv
serializeTo = c2is2r3-ner-model.ser.gz
map = word=0,answer=1

useClassFeature=true
useWord=true
useNGrams=true
noMidNGrams=true
maxNGramLeng=6
usePrev=true
useNext=true
useSequences=true
usePrevSequences=true
maxLeft=1
useTypeSeqs=true
useTypeSeqs2=true
useTypeySequences=true
wordShape=chris2useLC
useDisjunctive=true
```

This is the Custom Classifier:

```
java -cp  stanford-corenlp-3.5.2.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -prop c2is2r3.prop
```

Combining models

```
java -cp stanford-corenlp-3.5.2.jar -mx2g edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERClassifierCombiner -ner.model c2is2r3-ner-model.ser.gz,classifiers/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz -ner.useSUTime false -ner.combinationMode HIGH_RECALL -serializeTo c2is2.serialized.ncc.ncc.ser.gz
```

Testing

```
java -cp stanford-corenlp-3.5.2.jar -mx1g edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERClassifierCombiner -loadClassifier c2is2.serialized.ncc.ncc.ser.gz -map word=0,answer=1 -textFile c2is2r3.txt
```